# How do I improve the compressibility of my PNG images?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, bitmap, compression, png

I'd like to know how to ensure good compressibility on PNG images. Note that I'm not asking for how to compress PNG images well (using tools like pngcrush) but how to ensure that the image content in the PNG is more easily compressible.

My question is related to reduction of storage space requirements in a large scale image generation system.

The project will build and store user-generated images (Think something like an avatar creator) so the source pieces for the output are under our control. The composited PNG output files will be generated server-side and stored in a cloud storage service.

The upper estimate of generated images per month runs into millions, so every byte counts.

Are there any things we could consider when creating the original pieces that will go into the composite output images that will ensure good compressibility?

For example... Do colours matter? Are there good and bad colour gradients in source image data that produce larger output? Is heavy antialiasing good or bad? Are there lossy ways to treat source images to improve PNG compressibility?

Generally, are there any byte-saving tips at the point of creating the images in the first place?

Comment: If you're willing to change the images, then why not use a lossy compression method instead, e.g. jpeg?  You can dial in the highest compression level you find acceptable.

Comment: Because I need alpha transparency in the output.

Comment: Off-topic? The FAQ allows questions that cover specific programming problems. They do not *require* source code. My question is related to reduction of storage space requirements in a large scale image generation system. It was aimed at people who may have knowledge of the operation of the PNG file format. If that's not an on-topic specific programming problem then I don't know what is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG compression is based on local (one pixel neighbourhood) prediction followed by ZLIB compressing. Hence, if we are dealing with true colour (RGB) images,  you want lots of uniform zones, preferably on horizontal or vertical directions, or very smooth, so that the prediction errors are small. It also helps that the image has few colors, because then the prediction errors will repeat (and Zlib will compress that nicely). 
Because of this, a simple recipe to preprocess a PNG true colour image for PNG saving is *posterizing* it.
Of course, if you have really few colours, you have the alternative of saving it as an indexed (palette) PNG, which will make the image notably smaller, and where the considerations before (local smoothness) matter less.
Hence, the question is complex.

> Is heavy antialiasing good or bad?

Antialiasing plays nicely with JPEG, with PNG is harder to say: it makes the image smoother, but it creates more colours.

As one comment states, if you tolerate lossy compression (and if you don't need alpha) you'd usually prefer JPEG instead.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of "unique" regions in the image would increase file size. So one way to ensure better compression would be to have many regions in the image which are similar or even identical. For instance, if your images contain a subject, try and ensure that the background is plain white or black. Also try and reduce the number of colours in the image by binning or by blurring, to an extent that can be tolerated by your application's requirements. Hope this helps.